# Opencv Face detection Cascade compiler error in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, tesseract

In my IOS project I have implemented a tesseract sample, in this sample I need to integrate opencv. I have used [this sample project](https://github.com/samwize/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV), which has default tesseract and opencv.

But I tried implementing face detection with this project, using the below code,

```
 NSString* cascadePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                             pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_alt"
                             ofType:@"xml"];
    faceDetector.load( [cascadePath UTF8String] );
```

But I get the below error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "cv::CascadeClassifier::load(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Right now in build settings -> C++ compiler -> "default compiler" is selected. I have tries the compiler setting from this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4655/link-error-for-only-cascadeclassifier-under-243/). If I set like this the "Tesseract" code is getting error.

**Created faceDetector as below:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>{
    UIImagePickerController *mediaPicker;
    UIImage *takenImage;
    UIImage *processedImage;
    cv::CascadeClassifier faceDetector;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your existing "opencv2.framework" ( the one that has come up with your xcode project )

Replace it with the [official one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.2/opencv2.framework.zip/download)

NOTE: It does not contain symbols for "armv7s". It would still work on simulator and actual devices.